How can I modify the sentence "私は学校に行きます” to "ましょう” form?
If I wanted to answer the question "どこに行きますか。" in ましょう form with the answer being "I'm going to school," how can I modify the sentence "私は学校に行きます。" ? I found that the literal translation for "私は学校に行きましょう。” is "Let me go to school."

I found that the literal translation for "私は学校に行きましょう。” is "Let me go to school."  Where did you find that?  Because it is wrong.

I'm not sure if that's wrong but sure sounds weird. I'd say that, to change the sentence to the volitive ("ましょう form") you'll need to remove the 私は first (or change it to 私たちは).

The "-ましょう" form is all about suggesting what "you and me" should do. "-ましょう" is best remembered as "let us". That should be respected when adding a topic or subject to the sentence.
"私は学校に行きましょう。" makes no sense: You are talking about yourself "私は" and suggest what "you and me" should be doing is to go to school. This sounds strange.
However, you can add 私が to your sentence, like in 私が何とかしましょう. I am still making a suggestion what we should do, suggesting that I and not someone else do something about it. 私 is not the topic of the sentence.
Sentences like 私たちは行きましょう work, too.
There is a second form from the same roots, also called volitional form, the "でしょう" form used for likeliness. "私は学校に行くでしょう。" can mean "I will probably go to school". Perhaps you meant this one?

Not exactly; the following sentence is valid: 私が何とかしましょう

@Gui Imamura: That's true, but 私は何とかしましょう sounds strange to me...
